# Обработка нажатия кнопки на клавиатуре

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

При нажатии на кнопку стрелка (на клавиатуре) `(keycode 37)` нужно показать иконку на на 300мс, замет скрыть её. И так на каждое нажатие кнопки.
Я создаю переменную с типом `false` при нажатии кнопки, делаю её `true` тем самым отображая иконку, при нажатии запускается запуская таймер на 300мс по истечению которого другая функция возвращает `false`, тем самым пряча иконку.
Проблема заключается в том, что при частом многократном нажатии в какой-то момент иконка перестает появляться.

Может есть идеии как можно усовершенствовать этот подход или поменять на что-нибудь более толковое.

***P.S.***
В `css` есть класс `info_icons` для иконки. Когда иконка появляется для неё срабатывает анимация, то есть из прозрачной она становится не прозрачной и затем опять прозрачной. 
Проще говоря она плавно появляется и исчезает.

***P.P.S***

Так же для других кнопок есть `actions`. Суть такая же.
Я добавил один вариант, если получится придумать альтернативу или починить нижеизложенный код, то я смогу провернуть это дело с остальными кнопками :)

***html***

```
<v-icon v-if="replay_5" class="info_icons" size="50">
      replay_5
</v-icon> //Material ui icon
```

***Vue***

```
data() {
  return {
    replay_5: false,
  }
}

methods: {
  show_replay_5() {
    this.replay_5 = false;
  },

  onKeydown({
    keyCode
  }) {
    switch (keyCode) {
      case 37:
        this.replay_5 = true;
        /*some code*/
        setTimeout(this.show_replay_5, 300);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

***css***

```
 .info_icons {

        animation-name: fadeInOpacity;
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
        animation-duration: 0.3s;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
        border-radius: 100%;
        transform: scale(1.2);
        opacity: 0;

    }

    @keyframes fadeInOpacity {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
        }

        50% {
            opacity: 1;
        }

        100% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }
```

**Спасибо за внимание!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При использовании `setTimeout` и `setInterval` лучше создавать ссылки на них и при необходимости удалять, тогда не будет "зацикливаний".

---

Оптимальным было бы воспользоваться стандартными средствами анимации Vue: используя хук, например, **[`enter`](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2)**, менять значение, отвечающее за показ элемента на противоположное и тем самым скрывать его. Демо:

```js
// Создаем экземпляр приложения.
new Vue({
  // Корневой элемент, определяется по css селектору.
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    // Модель отображения кнопок-стрелок.
    arrows: {
      top: false,
      bottom: false,
      left: false,
      right: false,
    },
    // Чтобы не перебирать "свитчами" и "кейсами".
    keyMap: {
      37: 'left',
      38: 'top',
      39: 'right',
      40: 'bottom',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onKeydown({
      keyCode
    }) {
      if (keyCode in this.keyMap) {
        this.arrows[this.keyMap[keyCode]] = true;
      }
    },

    /**
     * Появление.
     */
    beforeEnter(el) {
      // console.log('beforeEnter');
    },
    enter(el, done) {
      // console.log('enter');

      // Перебираем свойства объекта,
      // устанавливаем для всех полей значение `false`.
      for (let arrow in this.arrows) {
        if ('object' === typeof this.arrows && this.arrows.hasOwnProperty(arrow)) {
          this.arrows[arrow] = false;
        }
      }
      // Коллбэк done не обязательно использовать, если
      // анимация или переход также определены в CSS.
      // done();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
/**
 * Стили для анимации.
 */

.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  animation: fade-in .6s;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}


/* Или такой вариант
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active { transition: opacity .6s;}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to { opacity: 0; }
 */


/**
 * Дальше стили для демки.
 */

*,
 ::after,
 ::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 188px;
  border: 1px dashed #08c;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'top top' 'left right' 'bottom bottom';
}

.wrapper:focus {
  border: 1px solid #08c;
  outline: none;
}

.icon {
  line-height: 60px;
  min-height: 60px;
  color: #fff;
}

.icon-top {
  grid-area: top;
}

.color-top {
  background: #fbc531;
}

.icon-left {
  grid-area: left;
}

.color-left {
  background: #c23616;
}

.icon-right {
  grid-area: right;
}

.color-right {
  background: #487eb0;
}

.icon-bottom {
  grid-area: bottom;
}

.color-bottom {
  background: #5fba7d;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <h3>Щелкните на блок для захвата ввода с клавиатуры</h3>
  <h4>Используйте стрелки клавиатуры, чтобы отобразить элементы</h4>

  <div class="wrapper" @keydown="onKeydown" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="icon icon-top">
      <transition name="fade" @enter="enter">
        <div v-if="arrows.top" class="color-top">Север</div>
      </transition>
    </div>

    <div class="icon icon-left">
      <transition name="fade" @enter="enter">
        <div v-if="arrows.left" class="color-left">Запад</div>
      </transition>
    </div>

    <div class="icon icon-right">
      <transition name="fade" @enter="enter">
        <div v-if="arrows.right" class="color-right">Восток</div>
      </transition>
    </div>

    <div class="icon icon-bottom">
      <transition name="fade" @enter="enter">
        <div v-if="arrows.bottom" class="color-bottom">Юг</div>
      </transition>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

---

В данном примере использованы повторяющиеся конструкции в HTML разметке, чтобы сохранить каркас для блоков, размещенных по сторонам света, т.е. это не шаблон, которому вы должны строго следовать.

Comment: Отличное решение! Спасибо!
Появился ещё вопрос, если нажать одновременно две стрелки, появятся сразу два направления, можно показывать только одно?

Comment: @ФессЛаеда, а как вы это себе представляете? Нужно дожидаться пока анимация не закончится у предыдущей? Вы написали `я смогу провернуть это дело с остальными кнопками` Проворачивайте : ) В этой строке дополнительные проверки выполняйте `if (keyCode in this.keyMap) {`

Comment: Понял, спасибо .